# Как сделать градиент полосками под углом?

Tags: css, css3

Как с помощью css сделать такой градиент?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте линейный градиент, и фильтр для ие:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(6, 201, 178, 1) 0%, rgba(6, 201, 178, 1) 25%, rgba(80, 211, 211, 1) 25%, rgba(80, 211, 211, 1) 50%, rgba(132, 221, 230, 1) 50%, rgba(132, 221, 230, 1) 75%, rgba(169, 227, 245, 1) 75%, rgba(169, 227, 245, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#06c9b2', endColorstr='#a9e3f5', GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот это вставить в класс градиента css. Цвета можно поменять.

```
 background: linear-gradient(135deg, #26c1a5 24%,#24e5d8 25%,#27cecb 49%,#00b0ba 50%,#27cecb 76%,#2ce8db 77%,#3498e5 100%); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#26c1a5', endColorstr='#3498e5',GradientType=1 );
```