# Линейный градиент , как делаются чёткий градиент по схеме?

Tags: css3, градиент

Вопрос с [mail.ru](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/204222673) но меня заинтересовало именно реализация !

Каким образом можно реализовать такой градиент :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я пытался так но получается размытый градиент:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red 20%, yellow 20%, red 30%, yellow 30%);
}
```

**Как это реализовать правильно согласно схеме ?**

Comment: [Как сделать градиент полосками под углом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733595/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC/733599#733599)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы краница была чёткой, надо одну и ту же позицию указать дважды подряд:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 20%, black 20%, black 30%, white 30%);
}
```

Чтобы чуть улучшить сглаживание для произвольных углов, можно добавить 1px:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 20%, black calc(20% + 1px), black 30%, white calc(30% + 1px));
}
```

А чтобы эта штука повторялась, надо использовать `repeating-linear-gradient`:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, white, white 10%, black 10%, black 20%);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, white, white calc(10% - 1px), black 10%, black calc(20% - 1px), white 20%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае вы тянете градиент под углом 45 градусов, до 20% красный, от 20% до 30% желто красный(вот тут как раз перелив) от 30% желтый. А вам надо например: под углом 45 градусов, красный до 25%, желтый от 25%, желтый до 50%,  красный от 50%, красный до 75%, желтый от 75%, понимаете?) вот так:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red 25%, yellow 25%, yellow 50%, red 50%, red 75%, yellow 75%);
}
```

То есть цвет должен быть как бы встык, участок от желтого к желтому, потом в тот же период от красного к красному, нельзя на разных размерах ставить разный цвет - от этого получается перелив. Это если полоски хотите получить.

Answer (score 2):

Попытки удались  , реализация

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(
45deg, 
black  5%, yellow 0%,
yellow 10%, black 0%,
black 15%,  yellow 0%,
yellow 20%, black 0%,
black 25%,  yellow 0%,
yellow 30%, black 0%,
black 35%,  yellow 0%,
yellow 40%, black 0%,
black 45%,  yellow 0%,
yellow 50%, black 0%,
black 55%,  yellow 0%,
yellow 60%, black 0%,
black 65%,  yellow 0%,
yellow 70%, black 0%,
black 75%,  yellow 0%,
yellow 80%, black 0%,
black 85%,  yellow 0%,
yellow 90%, black 0%,
black 95%,  yellow 0%,
yellow 100%, black 0%);

}
```